# Big-O notation for root functions

Tags: asymptotics, roots

I want to calculate the big-O notation for root functions such as $f(x) = (\sqrt{x})^{1/2}$ and $f(x) = 2^x\sqrt{2^{2x}}$. The domain of these functions is $\mathbb{N}^*$.

In the first function I tried, $$f(x) = (\sqrt{x})^{1/2} = (x^{1/2})^{1/2} = x^{1/4} = \sqrt[4]{x},$$ thus $f(x) = {\cal O}(x^{1/4})$. Is this the right way to approach this function?

In the second function I'm not sure my approach is correct, but here's what I tried.

$$f(x) = 2^x\sqrt{2^{2x}} = 2^x(2^{2x})^{1/2} = 2^x(2^x) = 2^{2x},$$ then $f(x)$ is ${\cal O}(2^{2x})$.

Can we simplify here the big-O ${\cal O}(2^{2x})$?

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: This is fine. You can write $2^{2x} = (2^2)^x = 4^x$ if you feel like it.

Comment: @JairTaylor I definitly feel like it, $4^x$ is a better representation of $2^{2x}$, I didn't think I could simplify it, thanks